# Why is the GetServer() method returning null?

Tags: c#

today I face an issue with some code I have written and really don't know where I have gone wrong, I'll keep it short and sweet basically the GetServer() method in the Faze class is returning null and I am really not sure why, but I was hoping you guys could help me with that.

I have left a few code snippets below of each class involved in the issue and where its initially called to give you a better idea on where things are going wrong.

Program.cs entry point..

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    Faze.run();

    while (true)
        Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Faze class

```
public static class Faze
{
    private static FazeServer fazeServer;

    public static void run()
    {
        Console.Title = "Loading...";
        fazeServer = new FazeServer("");
    }

    public static FazeServer GetServer()
    {
        return fazeServer;
    }
}
```

FazeServer class

```
public sealed class FazeServer
{
    private ConsoleWorker consoleWorker;

    public FazeServer(string lol)
    {
        LoadServer();
    }

    private void LoadServer()
    {
        consoleWorker = new ConsoleWorker();
        classLogger.Info("Server has been loaded.");
    }
}
```

ConsoleWorker class

```
class ConsoleWorker : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Timer consoleWorkerTimer;
    private readonly int consoleWorkerInterval;
    private static ILog classLogger;

    public ConsoleWorker()
    {
        if (Faze.GetServer() == null)
            throw new Exception("Server null..");

        consoleWorkerInterval = int.Parse(Faze.GetServer().GetConfig().GetConfigElement("console.worker.interval"));
        consoleWorkerTimer = new Timer(TimerElapsed, null, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(consoleWorkerInterval), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(consoleWorkerInterval));
        classLogger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ConsoleWorker));
    }

    private void TimerElapsed(object timerObject)
    {
        // Do something...
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        consoleWorkerTimer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

After following the trace, the code that interrupts it is my null check

```
if (Faze.GetServer() == null)
                throw new Exception("Server null..");
```

Before I added the if statement the line that caused an exception was

```
consoleWorkerInterval = int.Parse(Faze.GetServer().GetConfig().GetConfigElement("console.worker.interval"));
```

Why is GetServer() returning null, can anyone help?

Comment: Call Faze.run() first to initialize fazeServer, otherwise fazeServer is not initialized and null.

Comment: Because you calling `GetServer` inside a constructor of `FazeServer`. At that moment `Faze.fazeServer` variable is `null`

Answer (score 0):

I am after a few beers but in the class 'Faze' you have implemented a static field: 'fazeServer' and did not assign a value to it - therefore it is null. 
If you would like to assign a value to 'fazeServer' static field please implement in example a static constructor for the class 'Faze' - in example: '
static Faze() { fazeServer = new FazeServer("whatEverString");}'

and that should solve the NRE.

Regards,

P.Sz.

Answer (score 0):

Class fields are initialized to **null** by default so your code is the equivalent of:

```
public static class Faze
{
    private static FazeServer fazeServer = null;

    public static FazeServer GetServer() => fazeServer;
}
```

of course, calling **GetServer()** will return the unchaged value which is **null**.

If you want to initialize it yourself, use a **static constructor**:

```
public static class Faze
{
    private static FazeServer fazeServer;

    static Faze()
    {
        fazeServer = new FazeServer("");
    }
}
```

or the field initializer:

```
public static class Faze
{
    private static FazeServer fazeServer = new FazeServer("");
}
```

So it will be certain that you will get an instance when you call **GetServer()**.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `GetServer()` before a value has been set in the `fazeServer` static variable.

The call stack is as follows:

> fazeServer = new FazeServer("");
>    - LoadServer();
>    - - consoleWorker = new ConsoleWorker();
>    - - - if (Faze.GetServer() == null)

Or, in plain English:

- `fazeServer` is set to the return value of `new FazeServer()`
- `new FazeServer()` internally calls `LoadServer()`
- `LoadServer()` internally calls `new ConsoleWorker()`
- `new ConsoleWorker()` internally calls `Faze.GetServer()`
- `Faze.GetServer()` returns the current value of `fazeServer`

So the code which *sets* that static variable is internally trying to *read* that static variable before it has finished setting it.