# Method GetServer() returning null for unknown reason

Tags: c#

I have a project and one of the main methods is returning null when it is pretty clear to see I have assigned a value to it.

Program.cs:

```
using System;

namespace Sahara
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.Title = "Loading Sahara...";
            Console.CursorVisible = false;

            Sahara.Initialize();

            while (true)
            {
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sahara.cs:

```
namespace Sahara
{
    class Sahara
    {
        private static SaharaServer server;

        public static void Initialize()
        {
            server = new SaharaServer();
        }

        public static SaharaServer GetServer()
        {
            return server;
        }
    }
}

SaharaServer:

using Sahara.Core.Config;
using Sahara.Core.Logging;
using Sahara.Core.Server;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Sahara
{
    class SaharaServer
    {
        private readonly ServerStatusUpdater serverStatusUpdater;
        private readonly LogManager logManager;
        private readonly ServerInformation serverInformation;
        private readonly DateTime startedTime;
        private readonly ConfigManager configManager;

        public SaharaServer()
        {
            logManager = new LogManager();
            serverInformation = new ServerInformation();

            foreach (string consoleOutputString in serverInformation.ConsoleLogo)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(consoleOutputString);
            }

            logManager.Log("Loading " + serverInformation.ServerName + "...", LogType.Information);

            Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            configManager = new ConfigManager("Extra/Other/config.ini");

            startedTime = DateTime.Now;

            serverStatusUpdater = new ServerStatusUpdater();

            stopwatch.Stop();
            logManager.Log("Finished Loading! [" + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms]", LogType.Warning);

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
        }

        public LogManager GetLogManager()
        {
            return logManager;
        }

        public ServerInformation GetServerInformation()
        {
            return serverInformation;
        }

        public DateTime StartedTime
        {
            get { return startedTime; }
        }

        public ConfigManager GetConfigManager()
        {
            return configManager;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            try
            {
                serverStatusUpdater.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                if (logManager != null)
                {
                    logManager.Log("Error in disposing SaharaServer: " + exception.Message, LogType.Error);
                    logManager.Log(exception.StackTrace, LogType.Error);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But why is GetServer() in Sahara.cs returning null!!?!?!?!?

Comment: Where is your GetServer() call?

Comment: You're not actually calling the method anywhere.  You have to call a method in order for that method to return a value.

Comment: In a seperate class that is nothing to do with this question, I didn't want to pile up the question with classes that don't need to be read, it is simply called like this: "Sahara.GetServer();"

Comment: @David What do you mean by that?

Comment: This is not a complete, reproduceable example (please see [MCVE]).  You are assuming that `Initialize()` is called before your external call to `GetServer()`, but we can't deduce the same based on the limited example you have provided.

Comment: is `Sahara.Initialize` called at all if your `GetServer` call is in a different class?

Comment: @croxy you can probably assume so, since the call is in the main method.

Comment: GetServer() is called inside the ConfigManager constructor, this is why I never included it because I know it was called long after the Initialize() method.

Comment: This is still not reproducible for us. The code looks fine as it is.

Comment: Is it called in a _static_ constructor?  That _could_ get called before the `Initialize` call in `Main`.

Comment: While votes have been cast to close this question for the obvious reason of not including the errant code in the question, note that this is also a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416339/why-is-the-getserver-method-returning-null

Answer (score 3):

You call the `ConfigManager` constructor from within the `SaharaServer` constructor, so the constructor has not yet completed to set the `server` field and thus `GetServer` will return `null`.